# Angular typescript how to convert string to html object and pass it to variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have a function witch gets html content from file as a string. After that I made it as a html object. I can clearly see it in my console that it works. How to pass it from a service to a div element ?

**nav.service.ts** :

```
html: string;
      public  getZipFileContent(urlPath:string, pathInZip:string, ) {
        getFileContentFromRemoteZip(urlPath, pathInZip, (content) => {
          console.log(content);
          let html = content; 
          let htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
          htmlObject.innerHTML = html;
          console.log(htmlObject);
          this.html = html; // it's a string
          this.html = htmlObject // error : can't asign string as HTMLdivElement
        });
      }
    }
```

What I get now by adding **{{navSrv.html}}** in my component :

[image]

What I want to get :

## Hello

Console.log from : console.log(htmlObject);

[image]

**How to get htmlObject and use it as a variable ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can do it like follow if you want it in div only then

```
<div [innerHtml]="navSrv.html"></div>
```

Apart from this you can also do it like below :

```
<div #divID ></div>
```

And then bind it like this way

```
@ViewChild('divID') divID: ElementRef;

loadHtml(){
    this.divID.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.html;
}
```

The second part is useful when the html string is very much large.

**EDIT**

As your requirement if you have `<script>` tag then you can do if as follows

```
const element = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.html);
this.divID.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: What if HTML string got <script> in it, and I only see js as a string with [innerHTML].

Comment: what are you getting right now ? I think It will work but I doubt that the code under the tag won't work

Comment: Now i am using  <div [innerHtml]="navSrv.html"></div> . My navSrv.html is .html document with lot's of javascript code. I get javascript as a string.

Comment: Check my updated answer. May be you will get your answer.

Comment: I get error "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined" . 

I wrote in a class : 

@ViewChild('html') html: ElementRef;
  loadHtml(){
    this.html.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.navSrv.html;
  }

Comment: Have you given ID to div?

Comment: Yes, now I called this function on ngOnInit, thats why I got undefines. When I call it with a button it works, but there is another problem , maby we can go in chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169313/discussion-between-the-dictator-and-andrius-la).

Comment: @Angulandy2 Have you got the technique to run the script  within innerHTML?? If yes can you please let me know the process to run the script

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use innerHTML it will make sure your html will be shown correctly:

```
<div [innerHTML]="navSrv.html"></div>
```

Comment: Omg.. 2 hours for this?? Hate when this happens. Thank you

Comment: what if in that html is <script> tag where js is written ? I get js as a string.